# Jquery $.each() not iterating over all objects

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to iterate through all objects returned in json by an api.  Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.form-container').submit(function() {

          var $body = $('body');
          var $greeting = $('#greeting');

          // load streetview
          var streetname = $("#street").val();
          var cityname = $("#city").val();
          var address = streetname + ', ' + cityname;

          var bigImgUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x400&location="+ address +'';

          $greeting.text("So you want to live at " + address + "?");

          $body.append('<img class="bgimg" src='+bigImgUrl+'>');

          // NYTimes AJAX request
          var nytUrl = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q="+cityname+"&sort=newest&api-key=####";

          $.getJSON(nytUrl, function(data) {

              createStructure(data); // Call to recursive function

          });
          return false;
     });

    var createStructure = function (data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if (typeof value === 'object')
            {
                 alert(key + ": " + value);
                 createStructure(data[key]);
            }
            else 
            {
                 alert(key + ": " + value);
            }
        });

    };

    return false;
});
```

However it doesn't iterate through all them. Here is a screenshot depicting a part of the json returned by the API :

[image]

The code shows alerts for only entering `response`, all of `meta`(including children ie), entering `docs` and the `0` object(only some children elements). 
It skips all the remaining children of `docs` and the other outer objects.

Here is the link to the json : [JSON](http://pastebin.com/6neGEAQp)

Comment: Don't show us a screenshot, include the real JSON you are working with. Also tell us which JSON objects are *not* iterated over.

Comment: @Tichodroma how do I obtain the entire json?

Comment: You should know, the browser is running on your computer, not mine.

Comment: Call           http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=city&sort=newest&api-key=####" with the city you want and your api-key. The result should be the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use use a `for` `in` loop instead of `$.each`:

```
var createStructure = function (data) {
    for (var key in data){
        var value = data[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
            createStructure(value);
        } else {
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        }
    }
};
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q4vuc789/1

Comment: this does iterate through all objects but any thoughts on why `$.each()` wasn't working?

Comment: @Vineet Kaushik: There appears to be something special about your structure. `$.each()` *should* work the same. Every small test I tried (nested objects and arrays) worked with your original code. Very odd. Good to have an alternative method available :)